# Split tcp stream to several packets

Tags: tcp, wireshark

I have a pcap with tcp stream that is sent in one packet.
I am looking for a way to split the stream to several tcp frames,
for instance: say I have this pcap,

```
c2s : syn
s2c : synack
c2s : ack
c2s : datainfo
s2c : ack
....
```

The requested result is

```
c2s : syn
s2c : synack
c2s : ack
c2s : data
s2c : ack
c2s : info
s2c : ack
....
```

is there any tool that can help?

Comment: Whireshark is a program to monitor network traffic. Why should it change the network traffic?

Comment: in order to run some test on the firewall

Comment: Why should Wireshark be capable of hacking network traffic? It is a monitoring program.

Comment: Please describe the details of the test you're running and why modifying a PCAP will help.

Comment: The firewall view the data of the packets in order to find a variety of attacks. I want to test if it can find these attacks in case they were "cut". Anyway, I've found a way to do it with NetCat. In this tool every new line is a tcp frame.

Comment: @hillel_guy, then please post your solution as an answer below and accept that answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way not to edit a pcap, but to create a new transport easily.
Use the tool NetCat. It create a tcp connection to another host and you can write in the terminal the payload of the tcp. Each new line ends the packet. In that way it possible to create a new transport that has the data you want and divided to tcp frames in the way you want.

Also, I didnt do it yet, but you can create a pcap file of this new transport that you send by capture it with Wireshark.